# Rails:How to determine which code block holds the db connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application （4.2.5）running with puma (2 worker, 2-8threads).there are 10 connections configured in the database pool.but I got the timeout exception

couldn't obtain database connection in 5 seconds

I wonder which code block holds these 10 connections .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the full stacktrace when you see the error?

Comment: To see the activity of postgres you can see your pg_stat_activity view with a select, this way select * from pg_stat_activity;